# Reverse mapping in python

Tags: python

I have a dict like below.

```
{'I1': ['N1', 'N2', 'N3'], 
'I2': ['N2', 'N4'],
'I3': ['N1', 'N2']}
```

I want to reverse it in the below format. (i.e group the above dict based on the value and map the key to it)

```
{'N1': ['I1','I3'],
 'N2':['I1','I2','I3'],
 'N3':'I1',
 'N4': 'I2' }.
```

I tried this code

```
from collections import defaultdict
v = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items()):
    v[value].append(key)
```

But its throwing error "unhashable type: 'list' "

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://github.com/jab/bidict

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
reversedict = dict([(value, key) for key, value in mydict.iteritems()])
```

Comment: I'm getting this error " dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'"